# Android: different toolbar for each fragment in navigation drawer

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin

I'm making an Android app that have one activity and multiple fragments and a NavigationDrawer. Now all the fragments have the same toolbar, but i want a different toolbar for each fragment and i don't find the best method to do it. I read some tutorials but each person make it in a different way and I want to do the best solution
Can someone explain me the best way to do this (it is no necessary to write the code, only the idea)

Comment: I do one toolbar per fragment and it works great. Sharing the toolbar is a headache at best, and there's rarely a reason to do it in my experience.

Comment: @Nicolas so i made the xml for each toolbar and import in the fragments? and how the default toolbar of navigation drawer dissapear?

Comment: @AceStan the exampe?

Comment: For the navigation drawer you can make it a public field of your activity, then in fragment you get it with `((YourActivity) getActivity()).navigationDrawer` and you can set it up so that it can open the navigation drawer and show the "hamburger" icon.

Comment: @Nicolas If you share a toolbar, you get a cute animation of the hamburger morphing into a back arrow. :)

Comment: @Tenfour04 That's effectively something I gave up, but I'm sure this is achievable otherwise. I believe the Navigation Component has some utilities in that sense.

Answer (score 0):

My opinion is to use Toolbar as part of each fragment layout. That way you would have the possibility to customize it the way you need it. If there is something common about every screen you can make a custom toolbar and include it in every layout.

Example :

```
<LinearLayout
        android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/background_gray"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include layout="@layout/back_button_toolbar" />
 
        <!-- Your layout here... -->
</LinearLayout>
```

And the back button toolbar may be customizable as you like.
Something like this :

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/back_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/top_bar_height"
    android:background="@color/whitelabel_topbar_color"
    app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_navigate_back">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
        style="@style/ToolbarTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center" />

</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: this is the example of a fragment xml, isn't?

Comment: sorry for my question but i'm new in android developing... the navigation drawer have a default toolbar that put in each fragment, or not?
If yes how can i remove that to put my toolbar